# Export table contents to excel not working in IE 8 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, internet-explorer-8

Here, I have tried to export the table contents to excel. It is working fine in Firefox. But it is not working in IE 8. Can someone help me to resolve this problem? I have used jquery here. If it is possible using javascript also, I am ok with that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("[id$=excellink]").click(function(e) {
                    alert("$('div[id$=dvData]').html()");
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=dvData]').html()));
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <body>
            <br/>
            <div id="dvData">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Billing System</th>
                        <th>Market Code</th>
                        <th>Payment Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>RED</td>
                        <td>222</td>
                        <td>$103.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BLUE</td>
                        <td>111</td>
                        <td>$13.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GREEN</td>
                        <td>555</td>
                        <td>$143.00</td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" id="excellink" value="Excel" />

        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Not working"_... Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Does IE8 support `data:` URLs? My feeling is that it does not.

Comment: @Pointy I have the exact same thing in mind.. haha..

Comment: From [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/datauri): `Support in Internet Explorer 8 is limited to images and linked resources like CSS files, not HTML files. Max URI length in IE8 is 32KB.`

Comment: In IE 8, it is redirecting to new window and show the values of tables in URL..

Comment: Can someone please look into this problem? My requirement is to export the table contents to excel. That should work for IE 8.

Comment: @Pointy? Got any suggestion?

Comment: Don't think its related to your issue. But you should note that you should close the <head> tag before your opening <body> tag.

Comment: That will not be much issue...

Comment: @user3152748 are you the same person as "Dinesh Kumar"? It's confusing. Anyway I don't know what you can do to change the fact that Internet Explorer 8 does not support `data:` URLs other than to create the spreadsheet data on the server and make it available as a URL. You can then open the window with that URL and IE should be able to load it.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes I am the same person. Is there any samples in java to do this?

Comment: @DineshKumar well maybe; it's definitely non-trivial. There are Java packages for building .xls files, or you can build a .csv file instead (a lot easier). But exactly how that would work largely depends on your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try by adding bellow code specific to IE 8

```
    <!--[if eq IE 8]>
        <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("[id$=excellink]").click(function(e) {
                            alert("$('div[id$=dvData]').html()");
                            window.open('data:application/vnd.xls,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=dvData]').html()));
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });
                    });
                </script>
<![endif]-->
```